# newbie on sort.words

Tags: haskell

This expression:

```
sort words "fire water earth fire"
```

--- gives this error ---

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a]'
against inferred type `GHC.Base.String -> [GHC.Base.String]'
```

Could someone explain to me what is going on here and how to elegantly express sort.words?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want this:

```
sort (words "fire water earth fire")
```

when you do

```
sort words "fire water earth fire"
```

it's actually doing

```
(sort words) "fire water earth fire"
```

`sort` expects a list (`[a]`), but you're instead giving it `words`, which is a function takes a string and returns a list of strings (`String -> [String]`), hence the error message (it can't treat `String -> [String]` as a list of anything).

You can also do this:

```
sort $ words "fire water earth fire"
```

which is equivalent to the first version and might look neater.

Answer (score 3):

Function application is associative from the left, so that parses as `(sort words) "fire water earth fire"`. Needless to say, sorting the function `words` isn't going to work very well! As such, the error message is telling you that `sort` expects an argument of type `[a]` (that is, a list) but you've applied it to something of type `String -> [String]`, namely `words`.

You want either `sort (words "fire water earth fire")` or, to use the more common idiom, `sort $ words "fire water earth fire"`. The `($)` operator is just function application, but it has a very low, right-associative precedence, so it's often used in expressions like this to avoid writing out parentheses.